# Why 'static lifetime needed for owned variable by cloning

Tags: rust

I struggle a little with rust lifetimes:
why is `'static` lifetime needed for `run_trait_test`?.

I want it to behave like `run_concrete_test`

I read the documentation, searched stackoverflow and the rust-book but I'm obviously missing something.

```rust
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Test {
    test_string: String,
}

trait Example {
    fn tst(&self) -> ();
}

impl Example for Test {
    fn tst(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self);
    }
}

// compiles, no 'static here
fn run_concrete_test(tester: &Test) {
    let t = tester.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        t.tst();
    });
}

// compiles with 'static
// but F shouldn't be only static
fn run_trait_test<F>(tester: &'static F)
where
    F: Example + Sync + Send + 'static,
{
    let t = tester.clone();
    let store_t = thread::spawn(move || {
        t.tst();
    });
}

fn main() {
    //does run, no static
    let x = Test {
        test_string: "test string".to_string(),
    };
    run_concrete_test(&x);

    // doe sn't compile because of static
    // run_trait_test(&x);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html that's why

Comment: @hellow so what's the difference between the trait ref parameter and the Test ref parameter? Is the Test ref impliciltly 'static?

Comment: You're cheating ;) You use `tester.clone()` and that's why it works without the `'static`. If you remove that and move `tester` directly into the closure you will get the same error. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e51d8464bf0f6fdd04c4ba54518953a

Comment: @hellow sort of... :) Currently my effort goes mainly in the effort to get the code running and to understand how things work. I just tried to get the concrete implementation to a more general one. just hoped that I could move from `run_concrete_test` to `run_trait_test` without changes to the function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations) :

> The following traits are implemented for all &T, regardless of the
>   type of its referent:
>
> - ...
> - Clone (Note that this will not defer to T's Clone implementation if it exists!)
> - ...

Since `F` has `'static` lifetime boundary, `&F` is a type of shared variable:

- Without `Clone` boundary compiler will use `clone` from borrowed
  version of `F` (Simply it would just clone the reference)
- With  `Clone` boundary, compiler will use the implementation of `F`'s `Clone`

With all of these the code below will work as same with `run_concrete_test` :

```rust
trait Example {
    fn test(&self);
}

fn _run_trait_test<F>(tester: &F)
where
    F: Example + Sync + Send + Clone + 'static,
{
    let t = tester.clone();

    ::std::thread::spawn(move || {
        t.test();
    });
}
```

**Note**: Without `'static` lifetime boundary it is possible that `F` could be considered as some `T`'s borrowed type like `F = &T`

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c0bd7754aa136baac9e1af650c7f310)